# Grouping Joined Tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to join the products and attributes tables and group them by product id in order to get a list of products with their attributes. So I tried the following Entity Framework query:

```
    var productsWithAttributes = (from product in ctx.products
                                  join attribute in ctx.attributes on product.id equals attribute.productId
                                  select new
                                     {
                                          product = product,
                                          a1 = attribute.a1,
                                          a2 = attribute.a2,
                                          a3 = attribute.a3,
                                          a4 = attribute.a4
                                  } into t
                                  group t by t.product.id into g
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         product = g.Select(p => p.product).FirstOrDefault(),
                                         attributes = g.Select(r => new Attr()
                                         {
                                             a1 = r.a1,
                                             a2 = r.a2,
                                             a3 = r.a3,
                                             a4 = r.a4
                                         }).ToList()
                                     }
                                    ).ToList();
```

But this took around 70 minutes and when I looked into the SQL query it produced, I saw tens of subqueries with tens of joins.

Then I tried just to do the grouping on the sql server and did the projection into the desired structure on the application server. And this is the EF code for that:

```
    var productsWithAttributes = (from product in ctx.products
                                  join attribute in ctx.attributes on product.id equals attribute.productId
                                  select new
                                      {
                                          product = product,
                                          a1 = attribute.a1,
                                          a2 = attribute.a2,
                                          a3 = attribute.a3,
                                          a4 = attribute.a4
                                  } into t
                                      group t by t.product.id

                            ).ToList();
```

This took around 3 minutes. But the SQL prodcued by this query still looked complex with multiple subqueries and joins. I would epect something along the lines of:

```
select product.*, attribute.a1, attribute.a2, attribute.a3, attribute.a4
from product
join attribute on product.id = attribute.productId
group by product.id
```

Then I tried just the join without grouping:

```
    var productsWithAttributes = (from product in ctx.products
                                      join attribute in ctx.attributes on product.id equals attribute.productId
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          product = product,
                                          a1 = attribute.a1,
                                          a2 = attribute.a2,
                                          a3 = attribute.a3,
                                          a4 = attribute.a4,

                                      }
                                    ).ToList();
```

This took 1.5 minutes and the SQL code produced by EF was as expected.

In short, adding grouping to the join creates a convoluted SQL query which takes longer but it is still acceptable in terms of performance. But adding the final projection after this grouping produces an increadibly convoluted SQL query that takes and unaccepytable amount of time.

What is the correct way of creating this query with EF?

Comment: The problem is that `select product.*, attribute.a1, attribute.a2, attribute.a3, attribute.a4` in combination with `group by product.id` is not a valid SQL (at least for the most of the major relational databases). Second, the result shape needed is not natural for SQL. But why you ever need `join` and `group by` - with proper entity navigation properties the query should be trivial projection (`select`) with relatively simple SQL translation? Don't you have something like `public ICollection<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }` in your `Product` class?

Comment: @IvanStoev Unfortunately the database does not contain relations.

Comment: I see. What EF is this - 6, Core (version)?  Is it executing a single SQL query or N + 1 SQL queries? Can you share the classes used in the query along with the aforementioned information? The current information is not enough to give you a good advice.

Comment: @hakanviv Even when the database doesn't contain foreign keys you can define navigation properties. As said, it would make life much easier. You could do something like `product.Attributes`. At the same time you should wonder why there are no FKs. Consider adding them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create joined tables then all you have to do is create another table with both pk(Primay keys) and full join them instead of inner joining them or just joinig.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way of creating such query in LINQ to Entities is to use collection navigation property, or in case it is missing - [Group Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause#group-join) construct (`join ... into`):

> A group join produces a hierarchical result sequence, which associates elements in the left source sequence with one or more matching elements in the right side source sequence. A group join has no equivalent in relational terms; it is essentially a sequence of object arrays.

Something like this:

```
var productsWithAttributes = (
    from product in ctx.products
    join attribute in ctx.attributes on product.id equals attribute.productId
    into attributes // <-- emulate product.attributes property
    select new
    {
        product = product,
        attributes = attributes.Select(attribute => new Attr()
        {
            a1 = attribute.a1,
            a2 = attribute.a2,
            a3 = attribute.a3,
            a4 = attribute.a4
         }).ToList(),
     }).ToList();
```